# Ionic Background Geolocation - start tracking not working in interval

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am tracking the device location every 60 seconds. Which means the `startTracking()` function needs to be placed inside an interval. It seems when I do this, I'm not getting back a request, but in my console it looks like the gps is updating, the request just isn't being called. When I don't place the `startTracking()` function in an interval, it gets the initial GPS location (obviously) and it's not updating because it's not placed in an interval but the request is being sent.

location-service.ts

```
startTracking() {

    const config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
      desiredAccuracy: 10,
      stationaryRadius: 20,
      distanceFilter: 30,
      debug: false, //  enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
      stopOnTerminate: false
  };

  this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config)
  .subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {


  this.lat = location.latitude
  this.lng = location.longitude
  this.bearing = location.bearing
  this.speed = location.speed
  this.accuracy = location.accuracy
  this.timestamp = location.time

  this.backgroundGeolocation.finish(); // FOR IOS ONLY

  });

  this.gpsProvided = this.diagnostic.isLocationAvailable().then(res => {
    return res;
  });
  this.manifestID = this.events.subscribe('manifestid', maniID => {
    return maniID
  });

  this.backgroundGeolocation.start();
  }


 stopTracking() {

          let url = 'some URL';
          let request = {
              Latitude: this.lat,
              Longitude: this.lng,
              Speed: this.speed,
              Accuracy: this.accuracy,
              Bearing: this.bearing
          };
          let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
          let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
          let body = JSON.stringify(request);
          this.backgroundGeolocation.stop();
          return this.http.post(url,body,options).subscribe((data) => {
          });

 }
```

app.component.ts (without interval)

```
constructor(){
this.sendGPSStart()
this.GPSInterval()
}

sendGPSStart(){
    this.locationTracker.startTracking();
  }

  sendGPSStop(){
    this.locationTracker.stopTracking();
  }

GPSInterval(){
    setInterval(() => {

          this.sendGPSStop() 

      })
    }, 60000)
  }
```

app.components.ts (with interval)

```
constructor(){

this.GPSInterval()
}

sendGPSStart(){
    this.locationTracker.startTracking();
  }

  sendGPSStop(){
    this.locationTracker.stopTracking();
  }

GPSInterval(){
    setInterval(() => {

          this.sendGPSStart()
          this.sendGPSStop() 

      })
    }, '60000')
  }
```

Comment: Why is ‘60000’ a string in setInterval.  Should be a number.  Have you looked at ionic native geolocation?  Specifically the watchPosition function?

Comment: Sorry, it was a variable, changed it for this question, one sec. Geolocation doesn't track speed and bearing as well though.